# -setCornerRadius not found in custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am making a custom uitableviewcell class and inside this cell I have a square label.  I would like to round the corners of the label(dateBox) using this:

```
[dateBox.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
[dateBox.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

I do this is other classes and it works fine, but for some reason in the uitableviewcell subclass, I get the warning "setCornerRadius method not found".  Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to import QuartzCore and make sure it is an included framework in your project.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

or

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
```