# Warning: "No '-renderInContext' method found"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, compiler-warnings

I have this code, and it is working exactly as desired:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, for this line:

```
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

I am getting the warning (not error):

> No '-renderInContext' method found.

How can I have this warning, if in fact the method is working? If I were to simply comment out this line, my code fails; so clearly the line, and thus the method, are in fact working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add reference to the header file for `CALayer` -  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. You might also need to add the `QuartzCore.framework` to your project.

Answer (score 3):

It's saying this because the compiler can't find the definition of that method. You need to add this line:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

to the start of the `.m` file. You may also need to add the QuartzCore framework to your project.

(the reason your app works is that the method is available at run time)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having the [same issue as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443453/setcornerradius-not-found-in-custom-view/6443543#6443543). Make sure you add QuartzCore.